# Handling of suprema and infima in a proof of $\int_{a}^{b}(f+g)=\int_{a}^{b}f+\int_{a}^{b}g$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

I have proved the following statement:

"Suppose $f, g:[a, b]\to\mathbb{R}$ are Riemann integrable.
Prove that $f + g$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$ and $\int_{a}^{b} (f+g)=\int_{a}^{b} f+\int_{a}^{b} g$."

but I am a bit unsure about how to handle suprema and infima in the part where I prove that $\int_{a}^{b} (f+g)=\int_{a}^{b} f+\int_{a}^{b} g$ so I would be grateful if someone could check my proof out, especially in that part: comments are welcome.

My proof:

Let $P$ be a partition $x_0,\dots, x_n$ of $[a,b]$. Then
\begin{align}U(f+g,[a,b])\leq U(f+g,P,[a,b])&=\sum_{j=1}^{n}(x_j-x_{j-1})\sup_{[x_{j-1},x_j]}(f+g)\overset{*}{\leq}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(x_j-x_{j-1})(\sup_{[x_{j-1},x_j]}f+\sup_{[x_{j-1},x_j]}g)\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n}(x_j-x_{j-1})(\sup_{[x_{j-1},x_j]}f)+\sum_{j=1}^{n}(x_j-x_{j-1})\sup_{[x_{j-1},x_j]}g\\&=U(f,P,[a,b])+U(g,P,[a,b])\tag{1}\end{align} and
\begin{align}L(f+g,[a,b])\geq L(f+g,P,[a,b])&=\sum_{j=1}^{n}(x_j-x_{j-1})\inf_{[x_{j-1},x_j]}(f+g)\overset{*}{\geq}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(x_j-x_{j-1})(\inf_{[x_{j-1},x_j]}f+\inf_{[x_{j-1},x_j]}g)\\&=\sum_{j=1}^{n}(x_j-x_{j-1})(\inf_{[x_{j-1},x_j]}f)+\sum_{j=1}^{n}(x_j-x_{j-1})\inf_{[x_{j-1},x_j]}g\\&=L(f,P,[a,b])+L(g,P,[a,b])\tag{2}\end{align}

(* if $f, g : A\to\mathbb{R}$ are bounded functions, then $\sup_A (f + g)\leq\sup_A f+\sup_A g$ and $\inf_A (f + g)\geq\inf_A f+\inf_A g$).

Now let $\varepsilon>0$.
Since the upper Riemann integral is the infimum of the upper Riemann sums and the lower Riemann integral is the supremum of the lower Riemann sums there exist partitions $P_1, P_2, P_3$ and $P_4$ of $[a,b]$ such that

$U(f,[a,b])+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}>U(f,P_1,[a,b])$,

$U(g,[a,b])+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}>U(g,P_2,[a,b])$,

$L(f,P_3,[a,b])>L(f,[a,b])-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$, and

$L(g,P_4,[a,b])>L(g,[a,b])-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$

so if $P_5$ is the partition of $[a,b]$ obtained by merging the lists that define $P_1, P_2, P_3$ and $P_4$ we have (recalling the inequalities with Riemann sums): $U(f,[a,b])+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+U(g,[a,b])+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}> U(f,P_5,[a,b])+U(g,P_5,[a,b])\tag{3}$ and $L(f,P_5,[a,b])+L(g,P_5,[a,b])>L(f,[a,b])+L(g,[a,b]-\varepsilon\tag{4}.$

Putting $(1)$ and $(3)$ together we have:

$U(f+g,[a,b])\leq U(f,P_5,[a,b])+U(g,P_5,[a,b])<U(f,[a,b])+U(g,[a,b])+\varepsilon.$

Since this holds for every $\varepsilon>0$ it follows that $U(f+g,[a,b])\leq U(f,[a,b])+U(g,[a,b])\tag{5}.$

Putting (2) and (4) together we have:

$L(f+g,[a,b])\geq L(f+g,P_5,[a,b])\geq L(f,P_5,[a,b])+L(g,P_5,[a,b])>L(f,[a,b])+L(g,[a,b])-\varepsilon.$

Since this holds for every $\varepsilon>0$ it follows that
$L(f+g,[a,b])\geq L(f,[a,b])+L(g,[a,b])\tag{6}.$

$U(f+g,[a,b])\geq L(f+g,[a,b])$ together with $(5)$ and $(6)$ imply that $L(f,[a,b])+L(g,[a,b])\leq L(f+g,[a,b])\leq U(f+g,[a,b])\leq U(f,[a,b])+U(g,[a,b])$ from which, since $f$ and $g$ are integrable by hypothesis, follows that:
$$U(f+g,[a,b])=L(f+g,[a,b])=\int_{a}^{b}(f+g)=\int_{a}^{b}f+\int_{a}^{b}g,$$ as desired. $\square$

Comment: The key point should be this: Once you know $f+g$ is integrable, you know that $\int_a^b (f+g)$ is the unique number between all upper and lower sums. Thus, if you just show that $\int_a^b f + \int_a^b g$ has that property, then you're done. I find your argument a bit too hard to read, so I'm not going to be more helpful than that. But see if your proof actually shows this (or make it do so!).

Comment: @Ted Shifrin thank you for your interest in my question; I think my proof does show this and my only doubt is whether I have handled sup and inf correctly in the last few lines (see after the statement "I am not sure about the correctness of what follows"). P. S. I am also reading your book "Multivariable Mathematics" and it's great :)

Comment: I don’t see that you’re following my path at all. Your ** claims are not generally valid, no. Think about sequences $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$. Let $x_n = (-1)^n = -y_n$. Is the sup of the sum the sum of the sups? The inequalities are exactly backwards from what you need, I think. The sum of sets is not the appropriate notion here.

Comment: @TedShifrin That is what I suspected about those claims. I have edited my proof extensively and it should be better now. Thanks for the feedback.